# select unique data from a table with similar id data field

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: order_status_data2 table]

I am trying to retrieve unique values from the table above (order_status_data2). I would like to get the most recent order with the following fields: **id,order_id and status_id**. High id field value signifies the most recent item i.e.

4 - 56 - 4

8 - 52 - 6

7 - 6 - 2

9 - 8 - 2

etc.

I have tried the following query but not getting the desired result, esp the status_id field:

```
 select max(id) as id, order_id, status_id from order_status_data2 group by order_id
```

This is the result am getting:
[image: query results]

How would i formulate the query to get the desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
select d.*
from order_status_data2 d
join (select max(id) mxid from order_status_data2 group by order_id) s 
  on d.id = s.mxid
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_id, o.status_id
FROM order_status_data2 o
JOIN (SELECT order_id, MAX(id) maxid
      FROM order_status_data2
      GROUP BY order_id) m
ON o.order_id = m.order_id AND o.id = m.maxid
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5ccf/1)

In your query, you didn't put any constraints on `status_id`, so it picked it from an arbitrary row in the group. Selecting `max(id)` doesn't make it choose `status_id` from the row that happens to have that value, you need a join to select a specific row for all the non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Query.This will help you

```
SELECT id ,orderid,statusid 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT max(id) FROM table_name GROUP BY orderid 
)
ORDER BY statusid
```

You can refer this [Sql_Fiddle_link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2658c/4) which uses your example.